# Checking mobile number conditions in swift

Tags: swift

I want to get my cell phone number and check if it fits the conditions.
The condition I want is ***********.
Of course * should be expressed as a number.

Comment: Welcome Lisa. Two questions: 1) what have you tried so far? 2) what about users from different countries that may have different conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using a regular expression.

```swift
func isValidPhone(phone: String?) -> Bool {
        guard phone != nil else { return false }

        let phoneRegEx = "[0-9]{11}"
        let pred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegEx)
        return pred.evaluate(with: phone)
    }
```

If you add the string you want to this function, confirm that it meets the requirements.